# Computing $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty [i, \infty)$ and $\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty [i, \infty)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> Find $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i$ and $\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty A_i$ if for every positive integer $i$, $A_i = [i, \infty)$, that is, the set of real numbers $x$ with $x\geq i$.

My answer:

$$\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i = A_\infty = [\infty,\infty) = \infty < x \leq \infty.$$

Therefore, it is an empty set.

$$\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty A_i = A_1 = [1,\infty) = 1 < x \leq \infty.$$

Therefore, the set includes $[1,\infty)$.

However, the answer states that $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i$ represents $[1,\infty)$, and $\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty A_i$ represents an empty set.

Is the answer wrong and my answer is correct?

Comment: This is hard to read.

Comment: You need to explain why the first equality holds, because right now you're just stating the asnwer without any solution leading to it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your solution is that you seem to essentially just plug in $1$ and $\infty$ to obtain some intervals. You also seem to be mixing up union and intersection a bit. When you compute the union, you need $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i$ to include *all* the $A_i$. What you have obtained, however, contains *none* of them. If you get that a union of non-empty sets is empty, you should immediately realize that something is not right. Remember the general definitions of unions and intersections:

$$\bigcup_{j\in I}X_j=\{x:x\in X_j\text{ for some }j\in I\},\quad\bigcap_{j\in I}X_j=\{x:x\in X_j\text{ for all }j\in I\}.$$

Let's instead prove the following:

$$\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty [j,\infty)=[1,\infty),\quad\bigcap_{j=1}^\infty[j,\infty)=\varnothing.$$

Let's start with the first equality. So as $[j,\infty)\subseteq[1,\infty)$ for all $j\in\mathbb{Z}^+$, it follows that $\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty [j,\infty)\subseteq[1,\infty)$, and the reverse inclusion follows from the fact that $[1,\infty)$ itself is included in the union. Therefore $\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty [j,\infty)=[1,\infty)=[1,\infty)$.

Let's now do the second equality. This is a bit more tricky, as the right hand side is empty. So suppose $\bigcap_{j=1}^\infty[j,\infty)$ was not empty, and let $x\in\bigcap_{j=1}^\infty[j,\infty)$. Let $k\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ be such that $k>x$. Then $x\notin[k,\infty)$, contradicting that $\bigcap_{j=1}^\infty[j,\infty)$ is non-empty. It follows that $\bigcap_{j=1}^\infty[j,\infty)=\varnothing$.

We have thus shown that the provided answer is indeed correct, and yours is not. Hopefully this clears things up a bit.

Comment: A bit of overkill but still, +1 well explained.

Answer (score 1):

You have your $\cup$ and $\cap$ symbols mixed up. The symbol $\cup$ means a **union**, that is
$$A\cup B=\{x\mid x\in A~~\text{OR}~~x\in B\}$$

Whereas $\cap$ means **intersection**,
$$A\cap B=\{x\mid x\in A~~\text{AND}~~x\in B\}$$

Answer (score 0):

You have mixed up the intersection ($\cap$) and the union ($\cup$).

$$\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i = A_1 = [1,+\infty) = \{x\mid 1\leq x\}$$

and

$$\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty A_i = A_{+\infty} = [+\infty,+\infty) = \emptyset$$

Answer (score 0):

As the other answer points out, you've mixed up $\cup$ and $\cap$. Your first line then should be:
$$\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty A_i = A_\infty = [\infty,\infty) = \infty < x \leq \infty.$$
However, there are issues here because $A_{\infty}$ and $[\infty,\infty)$ are not defined. Moreover, there is no argument here.

You could argue as follows: Suppose $\cap_{i=1}^\infty A_i$ is non-empty, so there exists some $x\in \cap_{i=1}^\infty A_i$. Then $x\in A_i$ for all $i$. However, $x\not\in A_{x+1}$, a contradiction. Hence, $\cap_{i=1}^\infty A_i$ is empty as required.

Similarly, you have given no argument that $\cup_{i=1}^\infty A_i=[1, \infty)$, merely that it contains the set you wish it to contain. One solution here would be to note that $A_j\subset A_1$ for all $j>1$.

Answer (score 0):

Since
$$ A_1\supset A_2\supset\cdots\supset A_i\supset\cdots $$
one has, for any $n$,
$$ \bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i=A_1, \bigcap_{i=1}^n A_i=A_n. $$
Letting $n\to\infty$ gives
$$ \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i=A_1, \bigcap_{i=1}^\infty A_i=A_\infty=\emptyset. $$

Comment: And how do you define the limit as $n\to\infty$ here?

Comment: $\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigcup_{i=1}^nA_i=\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty$